# loop through json array and retrieve one attribute, gives errors also

Tags: ruby, json

i am new to programming in ruby, and i am trying to get the value of `json['earning_rate_hr']` but i get an error, `in '[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)`
i know and i understand the error, however this is not my main question here is   my  file :
`checkingchecker.rb :`

```
#require_relative '../lib/hackex/net/typhoeus'
require_relative '../lib/hackex'
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'

file = 'accounts1.txt'
f = File.open file, 'r'
puts "MADE BY THE PEOPLE, FOR THE PEOPLE #madebylorax"
puts ""
puts "--------------------------------------------------------"
puts ""

while line = f.gets
  line = line.chomp.split(';')
  email, password = line
  puts "logging in as " + email
  HackEx.LoginDo(email, password) do |http, auth_token, user|
    puts "getting info..."
    user = HackEx::Request.Do(http, HackEx::Request.UserInfo(auth_token))['user']
    puts "receieved user info!"
    bank = HackEx::Request.Do(http, HackEx::Request.UserBank(auth_token))['user_bank']
    puts "recieved bank info!"
    json = HackEx::Request.Do(http, HackEx::Request.UserSpam(auth_token))['spam']
    puts "recieved spam info!"
    puts json['earning_rate_hr'] #error line, the error is because this is an array, and it cant be turned into integer, i was wondering if there is a way to use puts on it without trying to make it an integer
    userchecking = bank["checking"]
    checking = userchecking.scan(/.{1,3}/).join(',')
    puts email + " has in Checking: BTC #{checking}"
    puts ""
    puts "--------------------------------------------------------"
    puts ""
    end
end
```

i tried to do `puts json`, it puts items like this one :

> {"id"=>"9867351", "user_id"=>"289108", "victim_user_id"=>"1512021",
>   "victim_ip"=
>   "86.60.226.175", "spam_level"=>"50", "earning_rate_hr"=>"24300", "total_earning s"=>"13267800", "started_at"=>"2015-11-01 07:46:59",
>   "last_collected_at"=>"2015- 11-24 01:46:59"}

what i want to do is select the earning_rate_hr for each one of them and add them together, however i do not have a clue on how to do that, since the error is not fixed and i cant get the value of it
ps : i tried turning it into a Hash, and i also tried using .first, but .first only shows the firs one, i want to show all of them, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you from line messenger, I haven't used ruby codes in a long time and this one keeps giving me cloudflare errors, I'm not sure if its because of server downtime/maintainance or whatever but yeah anyway heres your script, enjoy farming ;) -LineOne

PS, I changed a few strings to make it look a lil cleaner so you can see the spam income easier, and added the sleep (1) because sleeping for one second before reconnecting helps to prevent cloudflare errors
also you don't need to require json or rubygems in your hackex scripts because its required in the library so its all covered pre-user-input/script

```
require_relative 'libv5/lib/hackex'
while 1<2
begin
print'Filename: '
fn=gets.chomp
file = fn+'.txt'
f = File.open file, 'r'
puts "MADE BY THE PEOPLE, FOR THE PEOPLE #madebylorax" #helped by lineone
puts ""
puts "--------------------------------------------------------"
puts ""

while line = f.gets
  line = line.chomp.split(';')
  email, password = line
  HackEx.LoginDo(email, password) do |http, auth_token, user|
    puts "Retrieving Info..."
    puts''
    user = HackEx::Request.Do(http, HackEx::Request.UserInfo(auth_token))['user']
    bank = HackEx::Request.Do(http, HackEx::Request.UserBank(auth_token))['user_bank']
    json = HackEx::Request.Do(http, HackEx::Request.UserSpam(auth_token))['spam']
    cash_count=0
    tot_count=0
    json.each do |j|
      earn_rate = j['earning_rate_hr']
      total= j['total_earnings']
      cash_count+=earn_rate.to_i
      tot_count+=total.to_i
    end
    print "#{email}: current earnings: #{cash_count} per hour, Total earnings #{tot_count},"
    userchecking = bank["checking"]
    checking = userchecking.scan(/.{1,3}/).join(',')
    puts " #{checking} BTC in Checking"
    puts ""
    puts "--------------------------------------------------------"
    puts ""
    sleep 1
    end
end
rescue
puts"#{$!}"
end
end
```

Comment: lmao i knew it was you, add me on line lineone11, i hope im allowed to say that here :/

Answer (score 1):

Thats fine you can also calculate the total income of your farms by adding new variables at the top example `a=0` then adding the number at the end `a+=tot_count`

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
earning_rates = json.map{|e| e["earning_rate_hr"]}
puts "Earning rates per hour: #{earning_rates.join(" ")}"
puts "Sum of earning rates: #{earning_rates.map{|e| e.to_i}.inject{|sum, x| sum + x}}"
```

Comment: pretty close, i got the values, but what failed is the dollowing :

Comment: Earning rates per hour: 24300 18600 5550 3627 3060 2340 2160 2109 2040 2040 2025
 1938 1920 1872 1860 1860 1800 1800 1800 1800 1530 1530 1380 1380 1320 1320 1290
 1290 1140 1140 1140 1140 1140 1110 1050 1020 1020 1020 1020 1020 1020 1020 1020
 1020 1020 1020 1020 1020 1020 900 900 900 900 900 900 900 900 900 900 900 900 9
00 900 900 900 690
Sum of earning rates: 2430018600555036273060234021602109204020402025193819201872
18601860180018001800180015301530138013801320132012901290114011401140114011401110
10501020102...

Comment: Sum of earning rates: 2430018600555036273060234021602109204020402025193819201872
18601860180018001800180015301530138013801320132012901290114011401140114011401110
10501020102010201020102010201020102010201020102010201020102090090090090090090090
0900900900900900900900900900690

Comment: it joined them together, it didnt add them like +, i want to have one number

Comment: is there something like a foreach loop i can use ?

Comment: @JohnDoe I have just fixed it. The reason it was array of strings and not numbers.

Comment: instead of ``while`` loop  you may use ``f.each do |line|``

Comment: @JohnDoe instead of constructions like ``email + " has in Checking: BTC #{checking}"`` you should use ``"#{email} has in Checking: BTC #{checking}"``

Comment: so now earning_rates is an array ? meaning if i do this : sum = 0
array.each { |a| sum+=a }
 i should get the total earning rate right ?

Comment: i get this error if i do that :  `+': String can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)

Comment: @JohnDoe Yes, but it won't work because ``a`` is string, ``{ |a| sum+=a.to_i }`` will work.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked, thanks for sharing your knowledge maxim